# VSCode equivalent of Chrome's "Pretty Print" / "Format Code" functionality for debugging TypeScript/JavaScript code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

When debugging JavaScript code, you regularly encounter minified code. This code is hard to read for humans. To still "make sense" of the code while debugging, Chrome's debugger ships with a "Pretty Print" / "Format Code" functionality:

[image: Screenshot that shows Chrome's "Pretty Print" functionality]

I have to debug some server-sided Node.js code with Visual Studio Code that involves looking at the call stack that contains code in minified libraries. To make my live easier, I was wondering:

How can I achieve the same effect as caused by Chrome's "Pretty Print" functionality when debugging TypeScript/JavaScript code in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to open the command list (I don't know if you have the very same hotkeys) and, while debugging, search for "pretty print". It should show this:
[image]